# Are ladders more dangerous than guns?

Tags: mortality, safety, guns

> You know, studies show that keeping a ladder inside the house is more dangerous than a loaded gun. That's why I own ten guns, in case some maniac tries to sneak in a ladder.
>   - Grunkle Stan

I've been watching Gravity Falls and episode 10 contains this little gem. It sounds like one of those jokes that are actually true, but then again, it's a kids' show.

**It seems that Grunkle Stan might be misinterpreting studies showing that falls from a ladder kill more people annually than guns (which is probably true). Or is he actually correct and a single ladder in the house is more dangerous than a single gun?**

Comment: This isn't a serious claim. It is a joke. It isn't notable. [It also isn't clear.]

Comment: @Oddthinking The fact that it was used in a joke doesn't mean it's not a serious claim. I do not think the show's writers just made it up. It's been incorporated into several internet memes and spread on picture forums. Also, seriously, how is it not clear?

Comment: Its not clear because "more dangerous" is subjective.

Comment: On the off chance that this gets re-opened, I'll put this link here: https://www.ishn.com/articles/100802-how-big-is-the-problem-of-ladder-falls.  CDC tallies ~500 ladder-related deaths in the country a year (113 occupational, remainder household), a small fraction of gun deaths and fewer than accidental gun deaths.  The 500,000 non-fatal ladder injuries may exceed non-fatal gun injuries, though.  https://www.ishn.com/articles/100802-how-big-is-the-problem-of-ladder-falls

Comment: @Jamiec Why do you think so? There is probably more than one metric to choose from, but antlersoft clearly demonstrated that it is not hard to deal with.

Comment: @antlersoft Thanks, it may stay closed, but I'll just go and upvote a random (good) other answer of yours :-)

Comment: If you think it is a widely believed claim, please link to a better source of it than this. It is unclear, because there are many possible interpretations - that Antlersoft's comment ignores. Which of these does it mean? 1) More people die from ladder falls than gun deaths in the USA [laughably false, despite your "probably true" rating], 2) What about other countries (with lower firearm death rates)? 3) There are more death due to ladders *per ladder* than there are due to guns *per gun*.

Comment: 4) There are more deaths due to ladders *per household with a ladder* than there are due to guns *per household with a gun*. 5) Mortality rates in houses with ladders are higher than houses without, and than effect is stronger than the equivalent for guns - i.e. the mere presence of a ladder is dangerous. 6) Something else?

Comment: "falls from a ladder kill more people annually than guns (which is probably true)" - Umm, since that show is set in the USA, not a chance in hell.

Comment: @Oddthinking Hmm, there's more complexity than I expected. With that, I'm not sure if I'll be able to salvage the question :-(

Comment: @PoloHoleSet Well, I should have been more explicit - I wanted to say gun accidents vs. ladder accidents since that's probably what the original citation implied. I naturally do not expect ladder killings to be more frequent than gun killings. Also it's sad how unsafe the US are, I'll be sure to wear a bulletproof vest when I visit.

Comment: Fair enough.  I only reacted as strongly as I did because of the "kill" verb.

Comment: Well, I suppose I did trip over a ladder about a year ago and injure my shoulder.  I've never tripped over a gun.

Comment: I can see an interpretation where it makes sense.  Compare ladder accidents in the house with gun accidents **in the house**.  The total accidental deaths are similar but many of the gun deaths are hunting--and that's normally not done at home.

Comment: @LorenPechtel - Actually, a large number of serious hunting accidents are due to falling from a ladder.  (I'm being serious for once!)